# Syntax error when assigning an absolute path using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import and graph a .csv dataset using pandas, though when assigning the file path for the csv to be read, It reads as:

```
 File "C:\Users\17024\test.py", line 5
   dataframe = pd.read_csv(C:/PY_ABS_PATH)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code I used is bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import os

dataframe = pd.read_csv(C:/PY_ABS_PATH/scottish_hills.csv)
print(dataframe.head(10))
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, it's simply a matter of not surrounding a string with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the path of the file as a string, therefore you need to use apostrophes. Try with the following:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'C:/PY_ABS_PATH/scottish_hills.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it as a raw string using 'r' and quotes like

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'C:/PY_ABS_PATH/scottish_hills.csv')
```

or by replacing a single frontslash with double backslashes and adding quotes

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('C:\\PY_ABS_PATH\\scottish_hills.csv')
```